# citruspay magento on checkout shows error

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

**Error log file**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:362:"parse_ini_file() [<a href='function.parse-ini-file'>function.parse-ini-file</a>]: Unable to access /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/../../config/citruspay.ini
parse_ini_file(/home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/../../config/citruspay.ini) [<a href='function.parse-ini-file'>function.parse-ini-file</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or   directory";i:1;s:1290:"#0 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/Zend/Config/Ini.php(202):   Zend_Config_Ini->_parseIniFile('/home/iyurway2/...')
#1 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/Zend/Config/Ini.php(126): Zend_Config_Ini- >_loadIniFile('/home/iyurway2/...')
#2 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/CitrusPay_Moto_Block_Form_Pay.php(56): Zend_Config_Ini->__construct('/home/iyurway2/...', 'production')
#3 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2592): CitrusPay_Moto_Block_Form_Pay- >_toHtml()
#4 /home/iyurway2/public_html/app/code/community/CitrusPay/Moto/controllers/IndexController.php(9): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#5 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13969): CitrusPay_Moto_IndexController->indexAction()
#6 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18339): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#7 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17873): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20473): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /home/iyurway2/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/iyurway2/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:18:"/moto/index/index/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

When we try to check-out in the magento site, we are facing this issue. We are using CitrusPay payment gateway and the site should actually get redirected to citrus website. But instead of that we are seeing this error screen with reference to that log message.

Please help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your site compiler mode is on. Please disable compiler mode and check it.

Comment: Yes, the issue is with Compiler. I was facing same problem and disabling compiler worked for me.